# The simplest way to check for NaNs in columns (R)?

Tags: python, r

I'm python user learning R.

Frequently, I need to check if columns of a dataframe contain NaN(s).

In python, I can simply do

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [1,   2,   None, 3], 
                   'colB': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
df.isna().any()
```

giving me

```
colA   True
colB   False
dtype: bool
```

In R I'm struggling to find an easy solution. People refer to some apply-like methods but that seems overly complex for such a primitive task. The closest solution I've found is this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(colA = c(1, 2, NA, 3), colB = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
!complete.cases(t(df))
```

giving

```
[1] TRUE   FALSE
```

That's OKyish but I don't see the column names. If the dataframe has 50 columns I don't know which one has NaNs.

Is there a better R solution?

Comment: What's wrong with apply like functions?

Comment: There's a difference between `NA` and `NaN`

Comment: In case you need this check as part of a function, try `vapply` : `vapply(df, anyNA, FUN.VALUE = logical(1))`. `FUN.VALUE` specifies what you expect - here a logical vector of length 1 for each column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use anyNA: Checks for NA in a vector

```
df = data.frame(colA = c(1, 2, NA, 3), colB = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
sapply(df, anyNA)

colA  colB 
TRUE FALSE
```

### Edit

[jay.sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541783/the-simplest-way-to-check-for-nans-in-columns-r/70541887#comment124698260_70541887) is right. This will check for NaNs.

```
df = data.frame(colA = c(1, 2, NA, 3), colB = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))

anyNAN <- function(x) {
  any(is.nan(x))
}

sapply(df, anyNAN)
```

Comment: Did not know anyNA, nice one, +1

Comment: Equivalent to `apply(df, 2, anyNA)`.

Comment: Since it was asked for `NaN`, one answer should address that briefly, e.g. `is.nan(NA)`, `is.na(NaN)`.

Comment: @Maël; in this case yes but best not to use `apply` on data.frames as it coerces to a matrix, which is obviously an issue of there are any factor or character columns in the data.

Comment: thank you very much. I also didn't know there is ```anyNA```. The other references I searched didn't mention this function.

Answer (score 4):

The best waty to check if columns have NAs is to apply a loop to the columns with a function to check whether there is `any(is.na)`.

```
lapply(df, function(x) any(is.na(x)))

$colA
[1] TRUE

$colB
[1] FALSE
```

I can see you load the tidyverse yet did not use it in your example. If we want to do this within the tidyverse, we can use purrr:

```
library(purrr)

df %>% map(~any(is.na(.x)))
```

Or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~any(is.na(.x))))

  colA  colB
1 TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: The dplyr solution is short a couple of closing brackets - df %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~any(is.na(.x))))

Comment: Thank yoy CallumH for Sporting that. Misture corrected

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be:

```
df = data.frame(colA = c(1, 2, NA, 3), colB = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))

is.na(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      colA  colB
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE
```

**Update**, if you only want to see the rows containing NA:

```
> df[rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0,]

  colA colB
3   NA    C
```

**Update2**, or to get only ColNames with information about NA (thanks to RSale for `anyNA`):

```
> lapply(df, anyNA)
$colA
[1] TRUE

$colB
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Did not know `anyNA`, nice one, +1

Comment: Got `anyNA` from RSales answer, I just prefer lapply. So please upvote him too :-)

Comment: Oh, I see. Did that too.